# Android LiveData Shared between activities by Application Session

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm developing an app that use socket to receive messages from a chat.
I'm using an MVP approach and I store the data in a Singleton class named `DataBridge` like this:

```
class myApplication: Application() {

    val dataBridge: DataBridge = DataBridge()
    val deviceManager: DeviceManager = DeviceManager(this)

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this

        //init Logger
        TimberImplementation.init()

        //init Maps
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, MAP_ACCESS_TOKEN)
    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: InfiniteApplication
            private set
    }
}
```

I have the following scenario:

- Main Activity: create socket connection and update data in `DataBridge` class. It has a `ViewPagerAdapter` with 4 fragments. Each Fragment has it's own `Presenter`.
- Chat Activity: listen changes from `DataBridge` like `onNewMessage` (fired by `HomeActivity`) and display the chat

The question is: is a good practice to share Live Model by Application and make it accessible from presenter of different activities?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Your code does seem to be a *code stub*, since there are likely relevant parts missing, so the results you get from the code review might be suboptimal.

Answer (score 3):

Is a good practice to share LiveData?
**Yeah**

Here as you are using the data in databridge as a single source of truth and it is used hold data which is needed to be shared across multiple screen with live updates, Livedata is a really good option as it will also handle the lifecycle for you.

Android docs also has sample on [Extending LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) to create your own singleton data source which you may find helpful.

Also you can leverage the feature of [Object declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html) in kotlin to lazy initialize your DataBridge rather than in Application class.

Comment: Can you give some other example of Extending LiveData or can you tell what code should be there in StockManager? Thanks